# Why is message not appearing when using mail() function in PHP?

Tags: php, html, email

This is probably a noob question, but hey I'm a noob so here it goes. When I am attempting to send an e-mail with the mail() function, the message does not appear.

Live example: [enter link description here](http://viddir.com/page.php?page=2)

Here's my html code:

```
<div id="column-wide">
        <!-- DIV to push bottom of page down -->
        <div style="height: 430px">
      <div id="generic-container">

      <!--*********DO NOT EDIT ABOVE THIS LINE**********-->

<h1>Contact us!</h1>

<p>You can contact us at admin@viddir.com OR you can use our special mail press below.</p>

<br />
<form method="post" action="contactus.php">
    <textarea type="text" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
    <br />
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="send" name="submit" />
</form>

      <!--*********DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE**********-->

      </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
$to = "juggernaut1776@gmail.com";
$subject = "Message from Viddir";
$msg = $POST__['message'];

mail($to, $subject, $msg);
?>
```

Comment: change `$msg = $POST__['message'];` to `$msg = $_POST['message'];`

Comment: Bet you wont make this mistake again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$msg = $POST__['message'];
```

To

```
$msg = $_POST['message'];
```